# catting together different files in unix

Tags: unix, cat

I have a folder which has a bunch of files in them, and I'd like to cat together specific files. The layout is like this:

```
sample1_S99_L1_R1_001.fastq.gz
sample1_S99_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz

sample1_S99_L1_R2_001.fastq.gz
sample1_S99_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample2_S88_L1_R1_001.fastq.gz
sample2_S88_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz

sample2_S88_L1_R2_001.fastq.gz
sample2_S88_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

and so on for different samples.
I would like to cat sample1_S99_*_R1_001.fastq.gz into 1 gunzip file. So the samples that are grouped in the code above should be catted together.

Manually I would do something like this:

```
cat sample1_S99_L1_R1_001.fastq.gz sample1_S99_L2_R1_001.fastq.gz > sample1.R1.fastq.gz
```

and

```
cat sample1_S99_L1_R2_001.fastq.gz sample1_S99_L2_R2_001.fastq.gz > sample1.R2.fastq.gz
```

My idea was to sort of automate this procedure and I came up with this:

```
ls | awk -F '[_.]' '{print $1}' > test.txt
sort -u test.txt > names_final.txt
while read line;do cat $line_*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz > $line.R1.fastq.gz;done < names_final.txt
while read line;do cat $line_*_*_R2_*.fastq.gz > $line.R2.fastq.gz;done < names_final.txt
```

The problem I'm facing now is that these commands seems to cat all R1 files together. If i type for example

```
ls sample1_*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz
```

I only get the files I want to cat together. So I'm not sure were my mistake is here.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want blocks of `file_LX_001` to be together, then `file_LX_002` together, etc? The example is a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'd like to have those files together that have the same sample name, and the same R value. So R1 and R2.

Comment: So in the input you just updated, which ones should be together? all s99, then all s88, etc?

Comment: The ones that should be together all have the same R value, so R1 and R2. So the output for the sample files i provided should be: 

    sample1.R1.fastq.gz
    sample1.R2.fastq.gz
    sample2.R1.fastq.gz
    sample2.R2.fastq.gz

Comment: Note that in `$line_*_*_R2_*.fastq.gz`, this is substituting a variable `$line_` with a trailing underscore, not `$line` as you wanted.  Underscore is a valid character in identifiers (but a dash wouldn't be, so `$line-*-*-R2-*.fastq.gz` would work if the file names used dashes instead of underscores).  You probably need: `${line}_*_*_R2_*.fastq.gz` where the curly braces delimit the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$line_*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz` is parsed as `${line_}*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz` since underscores are valid characters in variable names. `$line_` with an underscore is empty, and so the glob `*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz` matches all sample names due to the leading asterisk.

Use explicit curly braces to fix this.

```
while read line;do cat ${line}_*_*_R1_*.fastq.gz > $line.R1.fastq.gz;done < names_final.txt
while read line;do cat ${line}_*_*_R2_*.fastq.gz > $line.R2.fastq.gz;done < names_final.txt
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a double `for`:

```
for i in {00..99}; do
   for j in 1 2; do
       cat sample1_S${i}_L*_R${j}_001.fastq.gz >> sample1.S$i.R$j.fastq.gz
   done
done
```

This goes through all files and `cat`s together those that have the same `sample1_SXX` and `_RYY`.

Note two things:

- you probably need `zcat` to `cat` gzipped files.
- the usage of curly braces when using the variables to define the scope of the name: `echo $a_c` tries to echo the variable `a_c`, whereas `echo ${a}_c` echoes the variable `$a` and then `_c`.

Comment: Multiple compressed files can be concatenated. In this case, gunzip will extract all members at once.

Comment: @JohnKugelman uhms, good to know. So the result of several `cat *.gz` is a compressed file as well?